# "Error occurred starting IDE-R" using Intel Manageability Commander

Tags: intel, amt, lenovo

I'm attempting to mount an .ISO file to a remote server using Intel Manageability Commander on a Lenovo TS440 ThinkServer. I've got the system configured to use Intel AMT, and I've enabled everything in the BIOS following [this guide](https://download.lenovo.com/servers/thinkserver_config_amt_ts140_ts440_tr.pdf) from Lenovo.

I've got the server connected in Remote Desktop and I've been able to have nearly full control of the remote system except when I try to mount an IDE-R device to remotely boot to an .ISO file I have. When I try to mount it the program spits out an error:

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MxbI6.png)

"Error Occurred starting IDE-R" Choosing any of the three options, Graceful, On Reset, and Immediate all return the same error. Attempting any of the mount options in any power state also returns the same error. I've also checked various other known good .ISO files such as Ubuntu, MemTest86, and unRAID and get the same error.

Googling this exact phrase worryingly returns exactly [zero results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3U2gf.png) from Google.

I've rechecked the Intel Management settings to verify the option for IDE-R is enabled, and I even toggled it off and on in the BIOS just to make sure. I verified that the motherboard, BIOS, Raid Card and AMT firmware is up to date (v9.1.45) but still get this error.

Does anyone have any idea why it's not allowing me to mount an IDE-R device? I'm willing to switch to a different AMT software if there's you can recommend. I'd like to get this working so I don't have to make a dedicated trip across town, unless that's what it's going to take to get this fixed.

Answer (score 0):

There is an Intel tool called MeshCommander.
They claim the IDE-R feature is still experimantal, but it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me as well in the current version (as of now 2.2.0) that uses Electron v8.5.5. I had to use Run as Administrator, and then IDE-R worked fine.

In previous version 2.0.345 I did not have to run as admin, or possibly IMC prompted from the start to run as admin.